# How to merge the arrays in two objects by key (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to write a function that merges two objects by their key. The objects both have an array of numbers as their value pair and it is the arrays I want to merge.

The input for this function is

```
const obj1 = {
  foo: [1, 2],
  bar: [3],
  baz: [4],
};

const obj2 = {
  foo: [5],
  baz: [6, 7],
};
```

The output should be

```
{
  foo: [1, 2, 5],
  bar: [3],
  baz: [4, 6, 7]
}
```

I tried using concat and spread operator however the answer I get is missing the "5" from the second object's foo. Also, I noticed with my current approach, if a key/value pair exists only in obj2, it will not be copied. Is there a better approach to this problem? Here's my code, please help!

```
function mergeByKey(obj1, obj2) {
  let resultObj = {};
  for (let key1 in obj1) {
    for (let key2 in obj2) {
      if (key1 === key2) {
        resultObj[key1] = [...obj1[key1], ...obj2[key1]];
      } else {
        resultObj[key1] = obj1[key1];
      }
    }
  }
  return resultObj;
}
```

```
**Output from code** 
{ foo: [ 1, 2 ], bar: [ 3 ], baz: [ 4, 6, 7 ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but it appears to work

```js
function mergeObjects(obj1, obj2){
        var response = {}
    
    for (let key in obj1) {
         response[key] = mergeProperty(obj1, obj2, key);
    }


    for (let key in obj2) {
         response[key] = mergeProperty(obj1, obj2, key);
    }
    
    return response;
}

function mergeProperty(obj1, obj2, property){
        let response = [];
    
    if(obj1.hasOwnProperty(property)){
            response = [...response, ...obj1[property]]
    }   
    
    if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(property)){
            response = [...response, ...obj2[property]]
    }
    
    return response;
}

const o1 = {
  foo: [1, 2],
  bar: [3],
  baz: [4],
};

const o2 = {
  foo: [5],
  baz: [6, 7],
};

console.log(mergeObjects(o1, o2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the distinct array of keys from both objects, then iterate that array and check for key in one object and not the other - therefore take that array, or if the key is in both objects, merge the arrays.

See below:

```js
const obj1 = {
  foo: [1, 2],
  bar: [3],
  baz: [4],
};

const obj2 = {
  foo: [5],
  baz: [6, 7],
};

//The output should be
//{
//  foo: [1, 2, 5],
//  bar: [3],
//  baz: [4, 6, 7]
//}

// keys from both objects, unique
const allKeys = [... new Set(Object.keys(obj1).concat(Object.keys(obj2)))];

// iterate all keys
const result = allKeys.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (obj1[c] && !obj2[c]) a[c] = obj1[c];
  if (!obj1[c] && obj2[c]) a[c] = obj2[c];
  if (obj1[c] && obj2[c]) a[c] = obj1[c].concat(obj2[c]);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could merge your two objects into one using the spread syntax `...`, this will give you the keys from both objects when you use `Object.keys()` on the merged object. You can then use `.reduce()` on this array of keys to create a new object. For each key, you can grab the array from obj1 (if it doesn't exist, default it to an empty array using `|| []`), concatenated with the array from obj2 (you can also default this if it doesn't exists to an empty array):

```js
const obj1 = { foo: [1, 2], bar: [3], baz: [4], };
const obj2 = { foo: [5], baz: [6, 7], };

const merged = {...obj1, ...obj2};
const res = Object.keys(merged).reduce((acc, key) => ({
  ...acc,
  [key]: (obj1[key] || []).concat(obj2[key] || [])
}), {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (assuming you don't know the object keys and that the values are always arrays).

```
function merge(x,y) {
  const keys = new Set([...Object.keys(x), ...Object.keys(y)]);
  const merged = {};
  for ( const k of keys ) {
    merged[k] = [ ...(x[k] || []), ...(y[k] || []) ];
  }
  return merged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that...

```js
const
  obj1 = { foo: [ 1, 2 ], bar: [ 3 ], baz: [ 4 ] } 
, obj2 = { foo: [ 5 ], baz: [ 6, 7] } 
, obj3 = { foo: [ 6 ], bar: [11], baz: [ 33, 14] } 
, obj4 = { foo: [ 88 ],  truc:[ 123 ]} 
, obj5 = { baz: [ 116, 17] } 
  ;
function mergeByKey(...objN )
  {
  let o_names = objN.reduce((list,objArg,indx) => // objArg is obj1, obj2, objN
    {
    Object.keys(objArg).forEach( k => // make a list of object name [ objIndexs...] 
      {                         // ob [ objIndexs...] on function argument
      if (!list[k]) list[k] = []
      list[k].push(indx)
      })  
    return list
    },{})
  let res = {}
  for (let o_name in o_names )
    res[o_name] = o_names[o_name].reduce((a,c)=>[...a,...objN[c][o_name]],[] )
  return res
  }

console.log( mergeByKey( obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5 ))
// or just - console.log( mergeByKey( obj1, obj2 ))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj1 = { foo: [1, 2], bar: [3], baz: [4] },
    obj2 = { foo: [5], baz: [6, 7] },
  merged = Object.create( obj1 );

for( var x in obj2 )
    merged[ x ] = obj1[ x ].concat( obj2[ x ] )
;
console.log( merged )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your challenge outside a function, but it works and it is easy to implement it in a function if you would like that, and the result is as you wanted:

````
// first create an array with all the keys from both objects
let keys = Object.keys(obj1).concat(Object.keys(obj2));

// Then remove/filter the duplicates keys
let uniqueKeys = keys.filter((c, index) => {
    return keys.indexOf(c) === index;
});

//at last do the merge. us if statment to avoid concatenating undefiend elements

const obj3={};
for(let key of uniqueKeys){
  if ( Object.keys(obj1).includes(key) && Object.keys(obj2).includes(key)){
      obj3[key]= obj1[key].concat( obj2[key]);
      } else if (Object.keys(obj1).includes(key))
        {
           obj3[key]= obj1[key];
        }
          else{
            obj3[key]= obj2[key];
          }

 
   
}
 
console.log(obj3);

     ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0RbI.png
````